# SQLITE3 exclude from import - data rows that are already present in a table - WITHOUT the use of a primary key

Tags: bash, sqlite

### Objective

I want to end up with an sqlite3 database that doesn't have duplicate rows within it, without a primary key. I want to be able to run my script multiple times but not have the same data get imported into my database if it is already present.

### Issue

Current database set up will import in data even if that same data is already present in the database (from an earlier import).

### Sample data - file.tsv

```
client1 account1    platform1   2020-04-05  44  advertiser1 5272
client1 account1    platform1   2020-04-06  44  advertiser1 10251
client1 account1    platform1   2020-04-07  44  advertiser1 14176
client2 account1    platform2   2020-04-05  44  advertiser1 5272
client2 account1    platform2   2020-04-06  44  advertiser1 10251
client2 account1    platform2   2020-04-07  44  advertiser1 14176
```

### Code

```sql
sqlite3 -batch database.db <<EOF
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clientdata_advertiser(
Client  TEXT,
Account TEXT,
Platform    TEXT,
Date_Delivered  DATE,
Advertiser_ID   INTEGER,
Advertiser  TEXT,
Impressions INTEGER
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wand(
Client  TEXT,
Account TEXT,
Platform    TEXT,
Date_Delivered  DATE,
Advertiser_ID   INTEGER,
Advertiser  TEXT,
Impressions INTEGER
);

.mode tabs
.separator \t
.import file.tsv wand

INSERT INTO clientdata_advertiser (Client, Account, Platform, Date_Delivered, Advertiser_ID, Advertiser, Impressions)
SELECT
    CAST (Client AS TEXT),
    CAST (Account AS TEXT),
    CAST (Platform AS TEXT),
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d',Date_Delivered),
    CAST (Advertiser_ID AS Integer),
    CAST (Advertiser AS TEXT),
    CAST (Impressions AS Integer)
FROM wand;
EOF
```

### Current output is code is run 2x

```sql
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select * from clientdata_advertiser ;
Client|Account|Platform|Date_Delivered|Advertiser_ID|Advertiser|Impressions
client1|account1|platform1|2020-04-05|44|advertiser1|5272
client1|account1|platform1|2020-04-06|44|advertiser1|10251
client1|account1|platform1|2020-04-07|44|advertiser1|14176
client2|account1|platform2|2020-04-05|44|advertiser1|5272
client2|account1|platform2|2020-04-06|44|advertiser1|10251
client2|account1|platform2|2020-04-07|44|advertiser1|14176
client1|account1|platform1|2020-04-05|44|advertiser1|5272
client1|account1|platform1|2020-04-06|44|advertiser1|10251
client1|account1|platform1|2020-04-07|44|advertiser1|14176
client2|account1|platform2|2020-04-05|44|advertiser1|5272
client2|account1|platform2|2020-04-06|44|advertiser1|10251
client2|account1|platform2|2020-04-07|44|advertiser1|14176
```

### Desired output if code is run 2x

```sql
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select * from clientdata_advertiser ;
Client|Account|Platform|Date_Delivered|Advertiser_ID|Advertiser|Impressions
client1|account1|platform1|2020-04-05|44|advertiser1|5272
client1|account1|platform1|2020-04-06|44|advertiser1|10251
client1|account1|platform1|2020-04-07|44|advertiser1|14176
client2|account1|platform2|2020-04-05|44|advertiser1|5272
client2|account1|platform2|2020-04-06|44|advertiser1|10251
client2|account1|platform2|2020-04-07|44|advertiser1|14176
```

### What I've tried

I've tried various ways of maybe doing this once the data is within the tables but couldn't seem to get it to work. I suspect the best way is to ensure that the rows don't get imported into the table if they are already in there but I haven't been able to figure out online how I might be able to do this without having a primary key - which my dataset doesn't contain. Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Philippe that command does the trick, but I'd like to avoid having to use `distinct` or `views`. Instead I'd rather the database not import the data, as I'm a cheap git who wants to keep my data storage low :^)

Comment: Create a temporary unique index on all the rows of the destination table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sqlite3 -batch database.db <<EOF
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clientdata_advertiser(
Client  TEXT,
Account TEXT,
Platform    TEXT,
Date_Delivered  DATE,
Advertiser_ID   INTEGER,
Advertiser  TEXT,
Impressions INTEGER,
UNIQUE(Client,Account,Platform,Date_Delivered,Advertiser_ID,Advertiser,Impressions) ##UNIQUE creates restrictions to ensure no row is the same based on all the columns defined
);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wand(
Client  TEXT,
Account TEXT,
Platform    TEXT,
Date_Delivered  DATE,
Advertiser_ID   INTEGER,
Advertiser  TEXT,
Impressions INTEGER
);

.mode tabs
.separator \t
.import file.tsv wand

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO clientdata_advertiser (Client, Account, Platform, Date_Delivered, Advertiser_ID, Advertiser, Impressions) ##INSERT OR IGNORE used to make sure the script doesn't blow up when there is a conflict with the UNIQUE statement.
SELECT
    CAST (Client AS TEXT),
    CAST (Account AS TEXT),
    CAST (Platform AS TEXT),
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d',Date_Delivered),
    CAST (Advertiser_ID AS Integer),
    CAST (Advertiser AS TEXT),
    CAST (Impressions AS Integer)
FROM wand;
EOF
```

Comment: found out that `UNIQUE` can restrict the row entries if all columns are assigned. `INSERT OR IGNORE` was then used to help make sure nothing blew up. comments placed next to the parts amended in my original code.